# How to redirect xhtml page to the same Request Scoped Bean?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Since the bean is in Request Scope, redirect creates a new instance.
If I try to put the bean in the View Scope, then I get the error of Property name is referenced to object narrower than the target View.

I'm displaying a tree, and when the user clicks on the tree node, say the 2nd node, the values corresponding to that node is displayed on the next page.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ThreeSixtyDegreeBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.name1}")
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String typeName;

    private List<AttributeDetails> attributeList;
    private List<Entity> entityList;
    private boolean rendered;
    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;

public void onNodeSelect() {

*selecting Data of the Node selected* 

                String a=fetchData();

                try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect(a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Where `a` is name of the xhtml page.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the data which gets generated when i click on the treenode,doesnot get reflected in the page,tht is due to request scope.

Comment: I want the data to get displayed.This is how it is:abc.xhtml and xyz.xhtml page having backing bean def.java which is in request scope.abc.xhtml page has Treenode,whn i click on the node,it fetches me data through onNodeSelect in def bean and this data i hv to display in xyz.xhtml page through the def.java bean,for which i use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(xyz).But no data is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can stash your stuff in the new JSF 2 Flash Scope to stash attributes between requests. Your `onNodeSelect()` can now look like this :

```
 public void onNodeSelect() {

      *selecting Data of the Node selected* 
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     Flash flash = context.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash(); //prepare jsf flash scope, to store user data pojo for the next view
     flash.putNow("myData", fetchData());
     try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect(a);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

On the destination page, you can then retrieve the data you stored in the flash scope using the `#{flash}` EL expression. It's essentially a `Map` so you just use the key of the value you stored ("myData" in the example I used above). to access it, use

```
     #{flash.myData.someMemberVariable}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view scope wouldn't have worked either. It lives as long as you're postbacking to the same view. A redirect basically creates a brand new GET request and would also have recreated the view scope.

In this particular case, you're better off performing data initialization in the redirected request, not in the postback request. You could do that by creating a normal GET link wherein you pass the necessary information as request parameters. Something like this:

```
<h:link value="#{node.name}" outcome="#{node.viewId}">
    <f:param name="someId" value="#{node.someId}" />
    <f:param name="name1" value="#{param.name1}" />
</h:link>
```

and then in the request scoped bean associated with the redirected page, you can just use `@ManagedProperty` or even the `<f:viewParam>` to set the request parameters as model values.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)